# Change Keyboard Layout with X11 API in Ubuntu

Tags: api, keyboard, set, x11

How to change keyboard Layout using X11 APIs.

Last post of Following link shows a way to get current keyboard layout.
[How to change Keyboard Layout (a X11 API solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230761/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-a-x11-api-solution)

I want similar APIs to set keyboard Layout.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: I've answered here: [How to change Keyboard Layout (a X11 API solution)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230761/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-a-x11-api-solution)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go very low level - use `ChangeKeyboardMapping` request, that way you can associate any keycode with any keysym. As tar as I know this is the only way if you don't use [X Keyboard extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/kbproto/xkbproto.pdf)

Comment: I found this API too. This function ask us to provide each & every key. 

I just want to change my layouts as requested by User. Only thing is I want to avoid command line solution. 

I found many solutions with command line

Still at a first glance, I dont find a API which change the Keyboard Layout in X Keyboard Extension.

If you could help me more would be much more easier.

Thanks

Comment: Look at setxkbmap source - http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/src/app/setxkbmap-1.2.0.tar.gz