# (Xlib) change keyboard input language and layout

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I want to know how can I detect and change the keyboard input language and even input layout.

Detect which keyboard layout is active? QWERTY, ...? and change it to another one.

And detect which language is active? en, es, ...? and change it to another one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Keyboard Layout (a X11 API solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230761/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-a-x11-api-solution)

Comment: Thanks @n.m., I have read that before, I couldn't find  clear solution, And it's not exactly what I need. I need to change input source too! For Arabic and Spanish too. Those solutions are just for changing keyboard layout I think :/ and I tested, Some of them not working. For example I couldn't compile the first answer, Cause there is no "XKeyboard.h" in my X11 libs :/

Comment: Of course it's not in X11 libs, it was a part of the solution (which is now lost). You want to check other solutions.